# <nav> element generated twice in my Angular component

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm working on an Angular application for a school assignment. I'm still very new to the framework. We're allowed to use templates from the internet so I decided to use this one: https://templated.co/broadcast

This template contains some scripts and I wasn't sure how to get these to work in Angular. Eventually I got it to work, but there is a very weird bug happening whenever I open up the menu.

[image]

As you can see, for whatever reason, the nav element is generated twice: once inside the app-root and once all the way down, below the scripts. Because of this, the menu opens twice.

From what I've read, using jQuery with Angular isn't quite a good practice, but I figured there'd be no other way around it because the template I downloaded uses these scripts.

I can't figure out what causes this, and there is no point in sharing countless code snippets, so I figured it would be better to share my repository: https://gitlab.com/stefanjaspers/angular-music-application/-/tree/development

Edit: I also suspect it is caused solely by jQuery, as the second nav element below the script tags isn't generated when I don't import the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, It's a Single page application means should be a single HTML page not multiple HTML page. In you app.component.html page seems to be `head` and `body` tag, You just remove it from your `app.component.html` page.

It's a navbar open twice when you click on menu icon. This is a temporary solution.

```
<!-- Header -->
  <header id="header">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
  </header>

  <!-- Nav -->
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Artists</a></li>
      <li><a>Register</a></li>
      <li><a>Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section id="banner" data-video="images/banner">
   ...
  </section>

  <!-- Main -->
  <div id="main">

    <!-- One -->
    <section class="wrapper style1">
      ...
    </section>

  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="footer">
    ...
  </footer>
```

Note: You just go through the angular material component for sidenav.
Ref: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples